# Rails-6: Mass import HABTM produces thousands inserts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, has-and-belongs-to-many, mass-assignment

After hours of googling for best practice, I came up here.

I have a new Foo object, and want to mass-assign thousands of bars to it, which I've pre-loaded:

```
@foo = Foo.create
@bars = Bar.find_all_by_some_attribute(:a)
```

What's the fastest way to do this? I've tried:

```
@foo.bars = @bars
@foo.bars << @bars
```

This results in thousands of insert queries being created.

**Is there a Rails 6 (Insert_all) way to solve my issue or do I have to solve it with the "m2m_fast_insert" gem or hardcoded SQL?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Join table setup, like:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items
end

class ItemsOrders < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :order
end
```

I believe you could insert many `ItemOrders` in this case (or whatever your join model is) with `insert_all`, which is new in Rails 6. If not your best bet is some amount of custom SQL. I did find another answer on SO that seemed to have a good starting point for the SQL: [What is the fastest way to create mass HABTM associations in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203420/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-create-mass-habtm-associations-in-rails)